# How to include with any property of class in entity framework?

Tags: join, entity-framework-core, include, relational-database, .net-7.0

```cs
public class City:IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ILKODU { get; set; }
    public string ILADI { get; set; }
}
        
public class Doctor : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string KIMLIKNO { get; set; }
    public string UNVANI { get; set; }
    public string ADSOYAD { get; set; }
    public int? UZMANLIK1ID { get; set; }
    public int? UZMANLIK2ID { get; set; }
    public int? UNITE1ID { get; set; }
    public int? UNITE2ID { get; set; }
    public int? UNITE3ID { get; set; }
    public int? BRICKID { get; set; }
    public string CEPTELEFONU { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public string SABITELEFON { get; set; }
    public string? ILKODU { get; set; }
    public bool? AKTIF { get; set; }

    //public int? CITYID { get; set; }
    //[NotMapped]
    public virtual City? CITY { get; set; }
    public virtual Expertise? UZMANLIK1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Expertise? UZMANLIK2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit? UNITE1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit? UNITE2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit? UNITE3 { get; set; }
    public virtual Brick? BRICK { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var result = await _doctorDal.GetAll(index: pageRequest.PageIndex,
        size: pageRequest.PageSize,
        include: d => d.Include(d => d.BRICK)
                    .Include(d => d.UZMANLIK1)
                    .Include(d => d.UZMANLIK2)
                    .Include(d => d.UNITE1)
                    .Include(d => d.UNITE2)
                    .Include(d => d.UNITE3));
```

I want to use the include function from Doctor to City. But I want to do the include operation on "ILKODU" but there is no field in my sql table, I want join with using "ILKODU".  How can i do?

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Also, show the `GetAll` method and the *exact* exception message (not "Entityframework says that..."). To do all this, please [edit] your question (don't post comments).

Comment: That's better (although the `GetAll` method is still not visible). To make the navigation property `Doctor.City` use `ILKODU`, this field should be an alternate key in `City`, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/foreign-and-principal-keys?source=recommendations#principal-keys). Of course `City.ILKODU` should be unique, Why can't `Doctor` have a `CityId`?